# Insect identification request - Is this a bed bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Spain and today I found several of these in my son's jacket. I am afraid they are bed bugs nymphs because last year we had a bedbug epidemic in some neighborhood houses.

The insect in the photo is about 1mm and has green spots in his body. Maybe they are just aphids that have been brought from the park.

[image: suspect bug]

Comment: *Green* spots? Probably not a bedbug, then. Bedbugs feed exclusively on blood meals, which means that any coloring you spot in the nymph would be **brown** or **red**.

Comment: As the answer suggests, I do not think that bed bugs would have green spots.

Answer (score 2):

I got curious and after some image search I got two candidates:

1. Plagiognathus repetitus

[image: Nymph of Plagiognathus repetitus]

2. Mullein Bug

[image: Nymph of Mullein Bug]

Comment: Great that you answered your own question! Can you add links to e.g. Wikipedia pages or other sources about these insects?